# Advantages of Blue Card vs. Permanent Residency

Tags: germany, blue-card, residency

Holder of EU Blue Card in Germany.

Are there any advantages to holding on to a Blue Card instead of applying for a residence permit, even if eligible for the permanent residency?

Is it even possible to keep the Blue Card for more than 4 years?

Answer (score 2):

> if eligible for the permanent residency

If you are eligible for Permanent Residency, you should really apply for it

Permanent residency means that your residency doesn't hinge on you being employed, contrary to a Blue Card which becomes invalid after 3 or 6 months of unemployment, and has no expiration regarding time.

[9 § AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0409)

> The permanent settlement permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis) is a residence title which is not limited in time

And it also allows you to seek naturalization

Comment: The process of moving to a different EU country should also be easier for a permanent resident, I think, though I don't know the details so I'm not certain.  At least it shouldn't be harder.

Answer (score 0):

There might be advantages if you want to switch the country, i.e. resettle to another country within EU. Bacause if you have a national permanent settlement permit, you might need to apply from scratch for a visa in order to change the country.
However, after you have lived 5 years in Germany, you can also apply for second permanent residence permit - Daueraufenthalt EU, which will give you even more rights than Blue Card.
With the new law, one can also apply fir German citizenship after 3-5 years living in Germany.